# Autowired spring bean null for cacheManager using ehcache spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, code-injection, ehcache

I'm still new to spring and I'm trying to get ehcache spring annotations setup correctly.  I'm using Spring 3.2.3 ehCache 2.4 and ehcache-spring-annotations-1.2.

When I try to access the reference to the cacheManager, it is always null.  All the jars are on the build path, ehcache.xml is in the classpath and there are no xml errors.  I've tried also including the classes in the component scan and using @Resource instead of Autowired.  I'm stuck!

Application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

 <context:component-scan      base-package="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean,com    .defaultPackage,net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager" />

<!-- ehCache Annotation settings -->
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
<bean id="ehCacheManager"   class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Wrapper

```
@Component
public final class MyCache implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private CacheManager ehCacheManager;

private getCacheManager() {
    return ehCacheManger; // this is always null
}...}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use the `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` as your cache manager.

Looking at [Spring caching documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-store-configuration-ehcache), you need to declare another bean to be your `CacheManager` created from the factory.